# Rails log VIP user activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, model, audit

We already use some log for our users activity to improve their experience. But we would like to increase our support by logging some important users activity.

I found some gems like `pfeed`or `audited` but it seems that none let us scope Model records objects.
I explain : Our goal is to have something like a `vip` bool on our User model that is the condition for the gem to record the activity.

Is there something or did we need to create our custom process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail
It's well maintained and has feature you need.

You can limit logging based on boolean field in you record like this:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :if => Proc.new { |user| user.vip? }
end
```

More details in doc here: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#2b-choosing-when-to-save-new-versions

Comment: thanks a lot I will try to find webhooks or papertrail events to monitor this :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @kirill-platanov I also succeed to override the model of version to trigger an alert when new version records are inserted in database :)